# Tablesorter does not sort (Jquery 1.8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, tablesorter

I did a lot of research concerning my question, but I didn't find an answer.

The `tablesorter` does not sort and I don't know why?.

Here is my test file. Can you tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#sortable").tablesorter();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Role</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>SuperAdmin</td>
                <td>SuperAdministrator</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Simon</td>
                <td>SuperAdministrator</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Manfred</td>
                <td>Administrator</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've got the jQuery file, the tablesorter.js...

the files are loaded correctly, cause I can read them (using firebug)...

Please help me, because I prefer not to write a `tablesorter` by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the headers (Username and Role), use `<th>` instead of `<td>`

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hz3r6/)

Use this:

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Instead of:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>Role</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Comment: well thank you! i came to this conclusion a few seconds before you wrote your answer :D